# How can I target a child class from the parent class in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This is pretty straight forward question in CSS so I kind of surprised it's proving to be difficult in styled-components. I would like to apply styles to `MultiWrapper`, but only when it's a child of `FormWrapper`. According to the [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components). All I need to do is reference the class in FormWrapper. Below is the relevant code. My React component calls both these functions and when the condition is true `FormWrapper` is the parent to multiple `MultiWrapper` classes that are next to each other. What am I doing wrong?

```
const renderFormType = form => {
    if (form.type === 'text') {
      return (
        <MultiWrapper key={form.prop}>
          <TextInput
            form={form}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
          />
        </MultiWrapper>
      );
    }
    if (form.type === 'dropdown') {
      return (
        <MultiWrapper key={form.prop}>
          <Dropdown
            form={form}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
          />
        </MultiWrapper>
      );
    }
    if (form.type === 'checkbox') {
      return (
        <MultiWrapper key={form.prop}>
          <Checkbox
            form={form}
            register={register}
            errors={errors}
          />
        </MultiWrapper>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  const multiForms = form => (
    <fieldset form={form.prop}>
      <Legend>{form.question && `${form.question}.`} {form.label}</Legend>
      <FormWrapper>
        {form.multiTypes.map(multi => renderFormType(multi))}
      </FormWrapper>
    </fieldset>
  )



 export const MultiWrapper = styled.section`
   display: flex;

`;

export const FormWrapper = styled.section`
  display: flex;

    ${MultiWrapper} {
      & + & {
        margin-left: 1rem;
      }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to add `margin-left: 1 rem;` to `MultiWrapper` only when it is a child of `FormWrapper`, all you have to do is the following:

```
export const FormWrapper = styled.section`
  display: flex;

    ${MultiWrapper} {
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
`;
```

see https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-kapitsa-sjqjhp

Answer (score -1):

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props this documentation will help you.You need to basically pass prop to section, your styled component will get that in prop and conditionally you can render any css you want.